# Using CSS3 transform: translate() to move an image over the current page's link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to CSS and am trying to incorporate some CSS3 features in a project I am working on.  What I am trying to do is create a transform:translate() that will 'drop' an image (say an arrow, or flag) over-top of a link that represents the current page.

So on the top of the page there is a navigation bar in the form of a `<ul>` that is floated to the right side of the screen.
ie. [Home][Profiles][Contact], etc.

What I am trying to do is have an image lower down and stay as the new background image of the specific `<li>` that corresponds to the current page, indicating what page you are on.

I understand how to change the background color of the `<li>` based on the current page, but I cannot figure out how to have the image lower over a specific `<li>` element using transform:translate() function. If anyone could suggest an approach to this problem it would be greatly appreciated! jQuery possibly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's actually a background image (defined in the css) you can't do that with CSS `translate`. If you create a JSFiddle with the HTML/CSS so far, we might be able to offer silutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will work something up and post it later.